# Morrisjs chart not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, morris.js

i'm trying to generate a chart using Marrisjs which i have done a few times before with no issue. However for some reason this one is proving to be very annoying! Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

```
<h4 class="card-title">Pedigree Chart</h4>
<div id="morris-line-chart"></div>
```

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    // LINE CHART
    Morris.Line({
        element: 'morris-line-chart'
        , resize: true
        , data: [
            {y: 'April',pedigrees_added: 1},
            {y: 'March',pedigrees_added: 0},
            {y: 'February',pedigrees_added: 3},
            {y: 'January',pedigrees_added: 0},
            {y: 'December',pedigrees_added: 0},
            {y: 'November',pedigrees_added: 0},
            {y: 'October',pedigrees_added: 0},
            {y: 'September',pedigrees_added: 0},
            {y: 'August',pedigrees_added: 0},
            {y: 'July',pedigrees_added: 0},
            {y: 'June',pedigrees_added: 0},
            {y: 'May',pedigrees_added: 0},]
        , xkey: 'y'
        , ykeys: ['pedigrees_added']
        , labels: ['New added']
        , gridLineColor: '#eef0f2'
        , lineColors: ['#009efb']
        , lineWidth: 1
        , hideHover: 'auto'
        });
    });
```

The problem is the information doesn't seem to be displaying properly. i'm guessing there is a syntax error somewhere.

[image]

Comment: sorry i just updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this library only works with dates x-axis. (https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html) change yor data like that:

```
  data: [
        {y: '2019-04',pedigrees_added: 1},
        {y: '2019-03',pedigrees_added: 0},
        {y: '2019-02',pedigrees_added: 3},
        {y: '2019-01',pedigrees_added: 0},
        {y: '2018-12',pedigrees_added: 0},
        {y: '2018-11',pedigrees_added: 0},
        {y: '2018-10',pedigrees_added: 0},
        {y: '2018-09',pedigrees_added: 0},
        {y: '2018-08',pedigrees_added: 0},
        {y: '2018-07',pedigrees_added: 0},
        {y: '2018-06',pedigrees_added: 0},
        {y: '2018-05',pedigrees_added: 0}]
```